# Erratic behavior from 'randomly' generated values in array

Tags: serial, arduino-mega, array, struct

Currently working on a data collection algorithm on the Arduino MEGA (ATMega1280) and I've run into a problem with some of the code I've written. I feel my problems may be stemming from the way in which I'm storing the sample points I've generated in arrays `ats1` and `ats2` or in the ways that I'm generating said sample points in `generate_tspairs`. Any insight would be appreciated.

I've defined a struct in an external file `structs.h`

```cpp
struct tspair{
  int t;
  int s;
};
```

I have a function defined in `generate_tspairs.h`

```cpp
    void generate_tspairs(tspair ats1[], tspair ats2[], int N, int reps1, int reps2, int reps3){

        int alpha = log(N)/log(2); //equivalent to log2(N) 

        for(int j =  0 ; j < reps1 ; j++){
            double randomDecimal = (double) random(1000)/1000;
            int r = (int) pow(2,alpha-1)*randomDecimal + 1;
            int s = 2*r - 1; //s is a random odd integer on the interval [1,N-1]

                for(int n = 0 ; n < reps2 ; n++){
                    double randomDecimal = (double) random(1000)/1000;
                    int t =  (int) N*randomDecimal;
                    tspair temp = {t,s};
                    ats1[(j*reps2)+n] = temp;
                }

                for(int n = 0 ; n < reps3 ; n++){
                    double randomDecimal = (double) random(1000)/1000;
                    int r = (int) pow(2,alpha-1)*randomDecimal + 1;
                    int s = 2*r - 1; //s is a random odd integer on the interval [1,N-1]

                    randomDecimal = (double) random(1000)/1000;
                    int t =  (int) N*randomDecimal;
                    tspair temp = {0,s};
                    ats2[(j*reps3)+n] = temp;
                }
        }
    return;
    }
```

After initializing and setting my two arrays of tspair structs, I am printing the values of the first array `ats1` using the following in `driver.ino`

```cpp
  int reps1 = 3;
  int reps2 = 5;
  int reps3 = 5;

  tspair ats1[reps1*reps2];
  tspair ats2[reps1*reps3];

  generate_tspairs(ats1, ats2, N, reps1, reps2, reps3);

  for(int i = 0 ; i < reps1*reps2 ; i++){
    Serial.print("t: ");
    Serial.print(ats1[i].t);
    Serial.print(" s: ");
    Serial.println(ats1[i].s);
  }
```

However, oftentimes I will receive the exact same values across multiple runs of `generate_tspairs` or when printing the values it will not stop at the end of my `ats1` but rather it will continue to print the same line ad infinitum. E.g.

```cpp
t: 815 s: 523
t: 975 s: 523
t: 244 s: 523
t: 8689 s: -26051
t: 31001 s: 29184
t: -25856 s: 6939
t: -2057 s: 6939
t: -2057 s: 6939
t: -2057 s: 6939
t: -2057 s: 6939
t: -2057 s: 6939
t: -2057 s: 6939
t: -2057 s: 6939
t: -2057 s: 6939
t: -2057 s: 6939
t: -2057 s: 6939
t: -2057 s: 6939
t: -2057 s: 6939
...
...
...
t: -2057 s: 6939
```

Comment: What are the types and values of `reps1` and `reps2`?

Comment: And why are you using  `n <= reps2` instead of `n < reps2`? If it's intentional it should be noted in comment why.

Comment: Where/what are the definitions of the ats arrays, and specifically, are they large enough that you haven't written beyond the bounds of either? What are reps1 and reps2, and the significance of their product, reps1*reps2, which you've used as the limit of the printing loop counter?

Comment: @JRobert I neglected to include that information originally, my apologies. Edited the driver.ino section of the question to include that

Comment: @KIIV That was a typo on my part, it is < in the code I ran.